# writeObject(this) cannot write object, java

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

I am using ObjectOutputStream to save object, but when I use .writeObject(this) to save it as a file, the material cannot be saved. The class I defined is already serializable.

```
public class LanguageModel implements Serializable {


private static LanguageModel lm_;

/* ******************************* */
//word -> count(w)
public static Dictionary unigramDict = new Dictionary();
//word_pair -> count(wi,wi+1)
public static Dictionary bigramDict = new Dictionary();

private static int wordIdCounter = 0;
/* ***************************** */


// Do not call constructor directly since this is a Singleton
private LanguageModel(String corpusFilePath) throws Exception {
    constructDictionaries(corpusFilePath);
}


public void constructDictionaries(String corpusFilePath)
        throws Exception {

    ...
    }

// Saves the object (and all associated data) to disk
public void save() throws Exception{
    FileOutputStream saveFile = new FileOutputStream(Config.languageModelFile);
    ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
    save.writeObject(this);
    save.close();
}

// Creates a new lm object from a corpus
public static LanguageModel create(String corpusFilePath) throws Exception {
    if(lm_ == null ){
        lm_ = new LanguageModel(corpusFilePath);
    }
    return lm_;
}

}
```

The class I defined is as follows:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Dictionary implements Serializable {

private int termCount;
private HashMap<String, Integer> map;

public int termCount() {
    return termCount;
}

public Dictionary() {
    termCount = 0;
    map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}

...
}
```

When I try `save.writeObject(unigramDict)`, it can save this variable properly. Since it is a large variable, I can simply check the size of the file. It is 5MB. When I switch to `save.writeObject(this)`, the size of the file is only 53 Bytes.

Comment: I don't understand the last paragraph.  You said that `save.writeObject(unigramDict)` gives you 5MB, then you said that `save.writeObject(unigramDict)` gives you 53B.  Which is it?  By the way, you could use a debugger to check that the `Dictionary` objects are actually being populated correctly before you save.

Comment: @DavidWallace I think the second `unigramDict` may be `this`, in the first case he save the `Map`, in the second case he save the `LanguageModel` object without the static field :)

Comment: Java Serialization only save non-transient and non-static fields.  This is because it is trying to save fields for that instance. Make any fields you want to save non-static.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the `static` modifiers.  Whoops.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're in trouble with the static fields which don't be save with `save.writeObject(this)`.

From the [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) javadoc:

> The default serialization mechanism for an object writes the class of
>   the object, the class signature, and the values of all non-transient
>   and non-static fields.

You should simply set `unigramDict` and `bigramDict` as non-static field, and access it with `LangugageModel.lm_.unigramDict`.
Maybe you can look at the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) instead of set all the field as `static`.